# fancy about some properties of Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can we use practically about the content in http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0124.pdf#page=3 starting from "2. Use of particular solutions to construct the general solution." ?

If I know a trivial solution of the Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form, can the content that mentioned above useful?